# Brent-Pollard factorization: What are the correct tortoise & hare indices in Brent's cycle finding algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, factorization, cycle-detection

Some time ago, I ported [this Python implementation of the Pollard-Brent algorithm](https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/pollard-rho-brent-integer-factorization/) to Clojure. It works, and works fast, too; that's not the problem. And when given identical non-random seed values and stepping functions, it reproduces the hare and tortoise positions of the Python code exactly.

But while I was working on it, I couldn't help but notice that the tortoise and hare didn't move quite the same way as I would expect based on the description of the algorithm in Brent's paper (or Wikipedia, or any other reference of choice).

Specifically, after the tortoise teleports to the hare's position, the hare steps forward by `distance` number of steps, and *then* steps an additional `distance` number of steps. Also, in the Brent-Pollard algorithm, the intermediate values are important as well; however, this code saves only the steps of the second hare "path".

Here are lines 6-18 of the Python code, with my comments:

```py
    while g==1:    

        # Tortoise (x) moves to hare (y)         
        x = y 

        # Hare (y) moves ahead by r steps
        for i in range(r):
            y = ((y*y)%N+c)%N

        k = 0

        # Hare (y) moves ahead by another r steps, 
        # with checkpoints at every m steps (the checkpoints are 
        # for the factorization; not part of Brent's cycle-finding algo proper)
        while (k<r and g==1):
            ys = y
            for i in range(min(m,r-k)):
                y = ((y*y)%N+c)%N
                q = q*(abs(x-y))%N
            g = gcd(q,N)
            k = k + m
```

I was going back over my code today and decided to test it for sure by mocking up a simplified version to show the indices. These are the indices given by the current code:

**Current version**:

```
Distance: 1
Tortoise at: 1
Hare starts at: 2
Hare path: [3]
Distance: 2
Tortoise at: 3
Hare starts at: 5
Hare path: [6 7]
Distance: 4
Tortoise at: 7
Hare starts at: 11
Hare path: [12 13 14 15]
Distance: 8
Tortoise at: 15
Hare starts at: 23
Hare path: [24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
Distance: 16
Tortoise at: 31
Hare starts at: 47
Hare path: [48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63]
Distance: 32
Tortoise at: 63
Hare starts at: 95
Hare path: [96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127]
```

Meanwhile, this is what I would expect the algorithm to do:

**Expected output**:

```
Distance: 1
Tortoise at: 1
Hare path: [2]
Distance: 2
Tortoise at: 2
Hare path: [3 4]
Distance: 4
Tortoise at: 4
Hare path: [5 6 7 8]
Distance: 8
Tortoise at: 8
Hare path: [9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
Distance: 16
Tortoise at: 16
Hare path: [17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32]
Distance: 32
Tortoise at: 32
Hare path: [33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64]
```

Even though the "expected" version reads better in Clojure when incorporated into the algorithm, it takes twice as long on average (which makes sense, looking at the indices).

My questions:

1. Is my expected output the "canonical" version of Brent's algorithm?
2. Is the current version still a correct implementation of Brent's algorithm?
3. Why does the current version work even though the hare path does not contain wholly consecutive indices?